# "Do miracles" or "Make miracles"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I've read both of them, but I don't know if both are equally correct and widely used.

Just to clarify after receiving the first answers: I meant real miracles (like god-related), not something that gave good results. So I guess the "work/perform" idiom doesn't apply, right?

Comment: "work miracles" is the usual expression.

Comment: You have to log on using Pedro's account if you want to edit your original post. http://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/154738 Notify a mod, click on *flag* tab, and explain the situation.

Answer (score 17):

***Perform or work*** a miracle  are more common expressions than make or do  a miracle.

***[Work/perform](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/miracle) miracles***:

> - to achieve very good results. 
>     *Her exercise programme has worked miracles for her.*

(OLD)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20a%20miracle%2Cdo%20a%20miracle%2Cwork%20a%20miracle%2Cperform%20a%20miracle&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperform%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0): *perform, work, do and make a miracle.*

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20%20miracles%2Cdo%20miracles%2C%20work%20miracles%2C%20perform%20miracles&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20miracles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20miracles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20miracles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperform%20miracles%3B%2Cc0): *perform, work, do and  make miracles*

Comment: Fromt he hyperlinked graphs, This would imply that "make miracle" is nearly never used.  However, those words may be seen as part of another phrase: [Ngram: make miracles happen](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+miracles+happen&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20miracles%20happen%3B%2Cc0) shows that phrase has experienced growing usage throughout my lifetime.

Comment: If you like, you can paste and copy this link on your answer https://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=make%20a%20miracle%2Cdo%20a%20miracle%2Cwork%20a%20miracle%2Cperform%20a%20miracle&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperform%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0 , use the image function.

Comment: and this one too https://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=make%20%20miracles%2Cdo%20miracles%2C%20work%20miracles%2C%20perform%20miracles&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20miracles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20miracles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20miracles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperform%20miracles%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

Next to "work miracles" and depending on context, consider ***work/do wonders***. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work+wonders%2Cdo+wonders&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20wonders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20wonders%3B%2Cc0)

> wonder
>
> a. An extraordinary or remarkable act or achievement: That
> teacher has worked wonders with these students.
>
> b. An event inexplicable by the laws of nature; a miracle. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wonder)